# Clock generator/synthesizer, Frequency generator/synthesizer. What is the difference?

Tags: clock

**EDIT**: Question simplified:

1. What is the difference between frequency generator and frequency synthesizer.
2. What is the difference between clock generator and clock synthesizer.

Comment: Most FPGAs have that capability built right into them, in the form of PLLs (phase-locked loops) or DCMs (digital clock managers). And you can certainly enhance their basic capabilities with additional logic, still within the FPGA. What are you really trying to do, and what FPGA(s) are you considering?

Comment: Your basic question is too wide to answer in this type of Q&A format - it is a vast, vast subject and trying to write an answer that satisfies the generality of the question is a mammoth task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Synthesizer** usually is a more complex device than generator. Synthesizer consists multipliers, dividers and mixers to generate desired signal. **Generator** is typically a device that generates signal with fixed parameters.

Check out the ICs. For example: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/clock-timing-clock-generators-plls-frequency-synthesizers/

Comment: Ah, so apparently my question was not so much related to electronics as it was to the definitions of the words "[generate](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/generate)" and "[synthesize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synthesize)" themselves. (Look them up, fellow non-englismen :)